# How configure quickfix/n failover

Tags: c#, failover, quickfixn

I am a beginner in Quickfix / n.
I want to run on Quickfix / n a primary server and a backup server to use failover. But I do not know how to configure the .cfg file of my primary server and the .cfg file of my backup.
I would also like to know if to do the tests from a server, it is necessary to run two applications, one for the primary server and one for my backup server.
I hope someone can help me with an example to activate the failover in quickfix / n in case the primary server is disconnected.

Code of my .cfg file:

```
 [DEFAULT]
 ConnectionType=initiator
 ReconnectInterval=2
 FileStorePath=store
 FileLogPath=log
 StartTime=00:00:00
 EndTime=00:00:00
 UseDataDictionary=Y
 DataDictionary=../../spec/fix/FIX44.xml
 SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.2
 SocketConnectPort=5002
 LogoutTimeout=5
 RefreshMessageStoreAtLogon=Y
 ResetOnLogon=Y
 ResetOnDisconnect=Y
 #Backup
 SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
 SocketConnectPort=5001



 [SESSION]
 # inherit ConnectionType, ReconnectInterval and SenderCompID from 
 default
 BeginString=FIX.4.4
 SenderCompID=CLIENT1
 TargetCompID=EXECUTOR
 HeartBtInt=30
```